# How to extract package contents at package install time?

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget-package, code-reuse

I'm working on a NuGet package that will store my common build/release scripts for reuse, as suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443814

As such, the package's contents should be extracted when it's installed (or overwritten when it's updated), so that the scripts can be pushed to the server as part of the containing project's repo, to be consumed in turn by that project's pipeline. Old news: execution of `Install.ps1` and `Uninstall.ps1` scripts are [deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/NuGet-3-What-and-Why/#powershell-install-and-uninstall-scripts), so that's not an option.

I built a simple test package from this NuSpec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>PipelineScripts</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>PipelineScripts</title>
    <authors>InteXX</authors>
    <owners>InteXX</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Common scripts for use in build/release pipelines</description>
    <copyright>Copyright &#169; 2021</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Script.ps1"></file>
  </files>
</package>
```

It installs fine into another project, but `Script.ps1` doesn't get extracted.

Is it possible to have my package's contents extracted at installation time? If so, how do I do this?

That said... if I'm barking up the wrong tree here, if there's a better way to accomplish my end goal of script reuse in pipelines, I'd be pleased to hear about it. (YAML isn't an option presently; I'm using Classic pipelines.)

Comment: I don't see what a NuGet package is getting you that just tagging the repo containing the scripts and checking it out by tag doesn't get you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that technique—could you elaborate?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation specifically addressing what you're discussing. But perhaps I don't understand the terminology well enough to do a proper keyword search.

Comment: Could something like this be what you're referring to: `git clone http://server/collection/project/_git/repo`

Comment: You can add a repo as an artifact source to a pipeline.

Comment: I like that idea, but... according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops-2020), one may add a repo as an artifact source to a *release* pipeline, but the same capability is not available for a build pipeline. Unless I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I ditched the package idea and went with `git clone` (example [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9372)). It works perfectly. Would you care to make it into an answer, so I can accept it?