# trying to understand how to reuse code in Azure pipeline templates

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Azure DevOps Server 2020
PowerShell 5.1

I'd like to call `Main` in File2 from File1 within Azure Pipelines.

I'm getting squiggly under `Steps:`

```
A list of steps to run in this job    
Unexpected property steps
```

File1

```
trigger:
  - none

pool:
  name: kids-pool
 

variables:
  - group: "rstest"

extends:
  template: 'testtemplate1.yml'
  parameters:
      yesNo: false

steps:
- powershell: |
    Main
```

File2

```
# File: testtemplate1.yml
parameters:
- name: yesNo # name of the parameter; required
  type: boolean # data type of the parameter; required
  default: false

steps:
#- script: echo ${{ parameters.yesNo }}
- powershell: |
    function Main {
      'hello world'
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431948/3537880

Answer (score 0):

You can not call just one function from the template. Pls, check the documentation: [Step reuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#step-reuse)

```
# File: testtemplate1.yml

steps:
- powershell: |
    function Main {
      'hello world'
    } 
    
    Main
```

---

```
# File: testtemplate1.yml

jobs
-job: A    
  pool:
    name: kids-pool
  steps:
    - script: echo This script runs before the template's steps
    - template: testtemplate1.yml
    - script: echo This step runs after the template's steps
```

Comment: Are there any advantages of doing all my work under one job with many steps vs splitting up into many jobs?

Comment: @Rod maybe using of several jobs as logical view with many tasks will be more simpler. One job will run all tasks one by one on one agent... if you need to use particular agent for some part of your task, you may also split your task into several jobs...
but one job to many tasks is a most often using